# Search program and files like dialog

Tags: c#, windows, windows-7

I'd like to create a small dialog able to find applications and run them as the "search program and files" dialog does in W7 and Vista.

Any pointers?

Comment: You generally want to avoid using pointers in a C# program.

Answer (score 1):

You might use [Launchy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/launchy/) as an example of a good application that does this same functionality. (It is written in C++.)

You might also take a look at [MightyBox](https://launchpad.net/mb) which is written in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers:

Take a look at [Directory.EnumerateFiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx) to find executables.

Check out [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) to start an application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to explicitly list the installed software (as Add/Remove Programs does) you can enumerate the instances of the [Win32_Product](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394378.aspx) WMI class. Just keep in mind that not all products register themselves here and they don't all provide install location information.

You could use [Directory.GetDirectories()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc.aspx) to list all subdirectories in the Program Files directory, and further enumerate down to guess the installation locations. Bit of a hack, though.

Comment: It would probably be better just to look at all the lnk files in the users Start Menu for programs.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't guarantee the location of the Start Menu directory for future versions of Windows, nor can you guarantee that the lnk file specification will remain the same.